# How to cast correctly from long to int?

Tags: c#

I have such method

```
        public int foo()
        {
            return (int) MainJsonValues[JsonKeys.DP_PORT.Value];
        }
```

This method  should make cast and return this value

There is how I call this method

```
myObj.foo()
```

So, it is very strange because as we can see value contains in `Dictionary`

You can see my debug on screenshot

[image]

So, as far as I see this method can't convert from `long` to `int`...

Error

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `is` and `as` operators do not cause conversion, only up/downcasts or unboxing

Comment: @BenVoigt anyway how to make it work?

Comment: Not generically, no.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski no it is not answer my question or you can post what do you mean exactly?

Comment: You object inside dictionary has `long` type, you can't cast it to `int` on the such way

Comment: @BenVoigt edited my question

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski edited my question, anyway which way I can cast from long to int?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You are casting, not converting. big difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A boxed value type may only be unboxed to *the unboxed type* or *the nullable unboxed type*. That is, if you have a boxed long, you may unbox it to `long` or `long?`, but not any other type. (See the comments for details.)

Therefore you need to do the conversion in two steps:

```
object x = 1L; // boxed long
long y = (long)x; // unboxed
int z = (int)y;
```

Comment: "not any other type"... not even `ulong`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I was wondering if anyone was going to bring that up! `ulong` is an interesting case. The rule in C# is that an unboxing unboxes to the boxed type. However, the rule *of the CLR* is that unboxing unboxes to *a type that has the same representation*.  An unboxed `ulong` has the same *bits* as a `long`, we just assign values to those bits differently, and the CLR allows an unboxing from boxed `long` to unboxed `ulong` and vice versa. The C# compiler could emit code to *prevent* this from working, but why make bigger, slower code just to enforce that rule?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Similarly the CLR allows a reference conversion from `long[]` to `ulong[]` and even though that would be illegal according to the strict rules of C#, you can write a C# program that does so. There are a bunch of situations where the C# design team and the CLR design team did not get quite aligned.

Comment: @EricLippert: So are `is` and `as` and cast-in-unboxing context not defined to return `false`, `null`, and `throw InvalidCastException` when the types don't match according to the C# rules?  These "same representation types" are a grey area where C# doesn't say whether `is` results in `true` or `false`?

Comment: Does that also mean that `((object)1L) is ulong` will result in different values depending on whether the compiler performs constant propagation or generates the runtime typecheck?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, `is` and `as` are in the same boat. `new int[0] as uint[]` is a compile-time error in C#, but `((object)new int[0]) as uint[]` is perfectly legal and works at runtime.

Comment: But the optimizing compiler could one day reduce `((object)new int[0]) as uint[]` to `default(uint[])` (i.e. strongly-typed null)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes! You can get constant folding involved in this mess too, and end up in situations where constant folding at compile time, and doing the same computation late bound at runtime give different answers. It is unfortunate, but these corner cases are rare.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not following you.  `new int[0]` is never `null`. `((object)new int[0]) as uint[]` just gives you an expression that at compile time has type `uint[]` and at runtime has type `int[]`, which is a little weird I agree.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're saying. You're saying that the *compiler* could deduce "this expression will never be of the given type, therefore I can generate it as though `as` returned null", but the optimization would produce a different result than runtime. Yeah, there are a bunch of optimizations like that where the compiler team cannot add them because it would break these compat scenarios. Basically once you cast to `object` or `dynamic` the compiler stops trying to do optimizations, figuring if you wanted an optimization you would not have inserted the cast!

Comment: Eric explains why casting works this way on  https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/ .