# Does operator fail to distinguish short[] from ushort[]?

Tags: c#, .net, short, ushort

Consider the following code:

I build it with `.NET framework 4.7.2`.

```cs
ushort[] a = new ushort[100];

if (a is short[])
{
    Assert.Fail("This never happens.");
}
object b = a;

if (b is short[])
{
    Assert.Fail("Why?");
}
```

The first test works *as expected* (`a` is not of `short[]`). My question concerns the *second test*, which, unexpectedly, does not fail.

Why is it so?

EDIT: added MSIL (Release, optimized)

```
 .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s   100
  IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.UInt16
  IL_0007:  isinst     int16[]
  IL_000c:  brfalse.s  IL_0018
  IL_000e:  ldstr      "Why\?"
  IL_0013:  call       void [(...).TestFramework](...).Assert::Fail(string)
  IL_0018:  ret
```

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061088/4728685) of Eric Lippert and comments to it. This [article](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) can also be helpful

Comment: The point here, that CLR allows unboxing from `ushort` to `short` and vise versa, therefore the second condition is works

Comment: "The first test fails" is confusing. To my mind the first test actually succeeds, because "Assert.Fail("This never happens.")" is not called. And the second test fails, because  "Assert.Fail("Why?");" is called.

Comment: @Polyfun - I edited to make it clearer, that I wanted to distinguish between `ushort[]` and `short[]`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - so, `a is short[]` would be always `true` in the first test, were it not for optimization?

Comment: @SurakofVulcan it's not about `optimization`... *it's all about boxing and unboxing conversions*...

Comment: @SurakofVulcan it's about boxing/unboxing, not about optimization

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks, I think I get it now, Eric Lippert's answer that you suggested makes it clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast correctly from long to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060876/how-to-cast-correctly-from-long-to-int)

Comment: @SathishGuru - yes, this is the post, that Pavel Anikouski suggested

Comment: I don't believe that there's any boxing and unboxing going on here at all - arrays are reference types and thus not subject to boxing. Even after casting a[] to a short array (via `object`), when accessing the elements of the short array there is no boxing happening. (You can verify this by inspecting the generated IL - there are no boxing instructions.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I added the MSIL, it really seems that `isinst` thinks that the two types are the same

Comment: Indeed - and it's possible to effectively "cast" an array of `ushort` to an array of `short`as shown in this [DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lWQDgD)

Comment: I don't understand why this question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, at least, not of the question it's supposed to be a duplicate of.

Comment: Another fun thing is that `Console.WriteLine(b is ushort[]);` and `Console.WriteLine(b is short[]);` both print `true`... So `b` is both `short[]` AND `ushort[]`. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qAuvvd)

Comment: I believe that the correct duplicate question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593730/why-does-int-is-uint-true-in-c-sharp